# Datetime type mismatch trying to publish a SQL CLR database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqlclr

I'm trying to stand up an old solution that's publishing a number of .net functions to a SQL Server database. But the attempt to publish to a new database is failing on a function that manipulates dates.

The function that's failing is:

```
[SqlFunction(TableDefinition="localtime datetime2", IsDeterministic=true, IsPrecise=true,
             DataAccess=DataAccessKind.None,
             SystemDataAccess=SystemDataAccessKind.None)]
public static DateTime ConvertFromUTC(DateTime utctime, string timezoneid)
{
    if (utctime.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
        utctime = DateTime.SpecifyKind( utctime, DateTimeKind.Utc );

    utctime = utctime.ToUniversalTime();

    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId( utctime, timezoneid );
}
```

The error message I get when attempting to publish is:

> Creating [dbo].[ConvertFromUTC]...
>
> (268,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider:
>
> Msg 6551, Level 16, State 2, Procedure ConvertFromUTC, Line 1
>   CREATE FUNCTION for "ConvertFromUTC" failed because T-SQL and CLR types for return value do not match.
>
> (268,0): SQL72045: Script execution error

SQL generated from the .net in an attempt to add the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertFromUTC]
    (@utctime DATETIME, @timezoneid NVARCHAR (MAX))
RETURNS TABLE ([localtime] DATETIME2 (7) NULL)
AS EXTERNAL NAME [database].[IntelligentTutor.Database.Functions].[ConvertFromUTC]
```

SQL definition for the version of the function in the existing database (which confirms that @MattJohnson was right about how it needs fixed):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertFromUTC]
    (@utctime [datetime], @timezoneid [nvarchar](4000))
RETURNS [datetime] WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS EXTERNAL NAME [database].[IntelligentTutor.Database.Functions].[ConvertFromUTC]
```

Comment: In addition to the suggestions noted in @Matt's answer, you should also consider the following: remove `TableDefinition="localtime datetime2",` from the attribute; use `SqlString` instead of `string` for `timezoneid` (which will require changing `timezoneid` in the `return` to be `timezoneid.Value`); and change `@timezoneid` from `NVARCHAR(MAX) `to NVARCHAR(50) or whatever size makes sense that is not `MAX`. Also, please be aware that the `TimeZoneInfo` class has a memory leak, which is why it requires the Assembly to be marked as `UNSAFE`.

Comment: For more information about working with SQLCLR in general, please see the series I am writing on this topic on SQL Server Central: [Stairway To SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/) (free registration is required to read their content, but it's worth it).

Comment: @srutzky - [`HostProtectionAttribute.MayLeakOnAbort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.hostprotectionattribute.mayleakonabort.aspx) does not mean "has a memory leak".

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks for that link. So just means "_can_ leak, _if_ aborted", right? As in, won't leak if allowed to complete successfully?

Comment: Right.  It's a highly unlikely event.  One could even argue that the attribute isn't necessary on this particular class, though there's not much can be done about that now.

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks for confirming that. I do recall a question on SQL Server Central from a few years ago in which someone was experiencing a memory leak using `TimeZoneInfo` and doing bulk updates. Of course, I didn't get a chance to fully investigate to see if calling `GC` would fix it or if it ever corrected itself over a long-enough period of time. It's possible the O.P. there was just impatient ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL function doesn't match the .NET method signature.  To make it match:

1. Change your the type of `@utctime` to `DATETIME2` instead of `DATETIME` in the function definition.
2. Change the return type to just `RETURNS DATETIME2` instead of returning a table with a nullable datetime2 column.

Also, note that if you are on SQL 2016 or later, or on Azure SQL DB, you don't need this function, as you can now use `AT TIME ZONE` instead.

Comment: I need to get the existing site running (all I got was a snapshot of code apparently copied off the web server and a DB dump, no documentation at all) before I can think about starting to apply a dozen+ years of skipped code modernization to it.  Would what I currently have have worked with an older pairing of .net/sql server; or do I need to climb even deeper into the rabbit hole trying to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @DanNeely There is no way that the code you posted in the question ever would have worked. The only way to return a table is if the return type in .NET is `IEnumerable`. And I don't think you can pass back a table without having a FillRowMethod noted in the `SqlFunction` attribute. This is all in addtion to the two items mentioned by Matt in this answer (which is entirely correct, btw, so +1 there).

Comment: Right.  It wouldn't have worked, because the .net code returns a single value, and your SQL wrapper expects a table.  Scalar-valued functions are different than table-valued functions.  [Read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-user-defined-functions).

Comment: ok.  I have a backup of the existing sites production database. Is there a way to view whatever was published to that so I can make sure whatever fix I do with the C# corresponds to whatever the previous dev actually managed to get into the system somehow?

Comment: Yes, but that's a different question.  Please give it a try and normal research first, and if you get stuck on that, then ask about that in a new question.  Remember, the primary goal of StackOverflow is to create question/answer pairs that are valuable to a large audience, not just to assist with your particular issue.  Thanks.

Comment: @DanNeely If this is presently working in Production, then at the very least you can script out the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). That should get you started :).

Comment: Followup posted:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45083492/how-can-i-get-the-definition-of-a-sql-clr-function-from-the-database